# Using fade on same elements with different classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fade

I have multiple divs and what I want to do is to fade out a div when you scroll it out of view. So far I can only get it to work with one div. Can someone please tell me how to do it?

This is my html:

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbo1">
    <h2>Hello, world!</h2>

    <p class="lead"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis error eveniet
        expedita,
        fugit itaque, iusto
        laudantium libero modi nesciunt odit officiis optio possimus ratione repellat, sit suscipit temporibus
        vitae
        voluptatum. </p>

    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
</div>

<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbo2">
    <h2>Hello, world!</h2>

    <p class="lead"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis error eveniet
        expedita,
        fugit itaque, iusto
        laudantium libero modi nesciunt odit officiis optio possimus ratione repellat, sit suscipit temporibus
        vitae
        voluptatum. </p>

    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
</div>
```

And this is the jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$(function(){
    var fadeBegin = 200,
        fadeFinish = 500,
        fadingElement = $('#jumbo1');

    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        var offset = $(document).scrollTop(), opacity = 0;
        console.log(offset);
        if( offset <= fadeBegin ){
            opacity = 1;
        } else if( offset <= fadeFinish ){
            opacity = 1 - offset / fadeFinish;

        }
        fadingElement.stop().animate({opacity: opacity}, 100);
    });

});

});
```

Comment: When you add `var fadingElement2 = $('#jumbo2');` below your last variable, and add `fadingElement2.stop().animate({opacity: opacity}, 100);` below your fadingElement.stop(). Does it work?

Comment: Well, it works on thoses 2 elements now but the fade at the same time.

Comment: Got it! Changed the jquery and now it works. Thanks for your advise though!

Answer (score 0):

i'm not good at english language. anyway i'm going to explain my code

1. fadeIn() – Display the matched elements with fade in effect.
2. fadeOut() – Hide the matched elements with fade out / transparent effect.

These two methods are support duration as parameter : slow, fast, or exact milliseconds.

The .fadeOut() method animates the opacity of the matched elements. Once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is set to none, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page.Durations are given in milliseconds; higher values indicate slower animations, not faster ones. The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds, respectively. If any other string is supplied, or if the duration parameter is omitted, the default duration of 400 milliseconds is used.

Now just Try this code.

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>fadeOut demo</title>
 <style>
 p {
 font-size: 150%;
 cursor: pointer;
 }
 </style>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="jumbotron" id="jumbo">
 <h2>Hello, world!</h2>
 <p class="lead"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis   error eveniet expedita,fugit itaque, iusto laudantium libero modi nesciunt odit officiis  optio possimus ratione repellat, sit suscipit temporibus vitae
    voluptatum. </p>
</div>
<div class="jumbo" id="jumbo1">
<h2>Hello, world!</h2>
<p class="lead"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis   error eveniet expedita,fugit itaque, iusto laudantium libero modi nesciunt odit officiis optio possimus ratione repellat, sit suscipit temporibusvitae voluptatum. </p>
 </div>
 <script>
 $( ".jumbotron" ).click(function() {
 $( ".jumbotron" ).fadeOut( "slow" );
 });
 $( ".jumbo" ).click(function() {
 $( ".jumbo" ).fadeIn("slow" );
 });
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try to post explanations instead of just code; "teach a man to fish..."

Comment: actually i'm not good at english language. that's the problem

Comment: The best way to learn is to try. : ) Your English seems fine to me! The man who never tries will never succeed.

Comment: I explained in my way.